# Ng-controller alert function called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some issues in using ng-include on my Angular page... the problem is that on some specific portion of the code( the included parts), the function attached to a component is called multiple times also if i click it only once.
How can I solve this ? Could it is a problem of the Routing or something related it  ?

Main.html

```
<body ng-controller="MasterController as masterCtrl"  id="primaryController">
   <div id="page" ng-controller="SessionController as sessionCtrl" >
     <div id="Central" ng-hide="masterCtrl.isMenuOpen()" class="ng-cloak" >
       <div id="Login" ng-controller="LoginController as loginCtrl" ng-if="!(masterCtrl.isUserLogged()) && !(masterCtrl.getIsLoading()) " ng-include="'Login/index.html'" class="ng-cloak"></div>
       <div id="RiepilogoDati" ng-if="masterCtrl.isUserLogged() && masterCtrl.isSelected(0)" ng-show="masterCtrl.isServicesLoaded()" class="ng-cloak" ng-include="'Home/index.html'"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

This is the MainPage... in this One I include the other components like Home/index.html

```
<form ng-submit="masterCtrl.getHome()">
   <div id="SiteList" ng-controller="SiteController as siteCtrl"  ng-include="'Home/SelectSiti/index.html'" ng-init="siteCtrl.getSites()" class="ng-cloak" ></div>
</form>
```

In Home, I include other page elements like Home/SelectSiti/index.html

SelectSiti/index.html

```
<div>
   <select name="select-site" id="select-site" style="width:80%" ng-model="siteCtrl.currentSite" ng-options="sito as sito.name for sito in siteCtrl.siti" ng-change="siteCtrl.setCurrentList()" >
     <option value="" disabled>Sito</option>
     <option ng-if="siteCtrl.isSiteEmpty()" value="Nessun Sito Disponibile" >Nessun Sito Disponibile</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

In the controller SiteController I have a function which I call after the press of the button in Home.html it is a rest callback... if I put an alert in this function, I can notice that it is executed more than one... I have read about the $scope Lose using the ng-include, so the question is... could it be an ng-include bad management?

Comment: Provide code? What routing framework?

Comment: can share your code ?.

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]